# Vue.js and async function call

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following Vue.js component:

```
module.exports = {
    data: function () {
        return { 
             searchText: "",
             searchResult: []
        }
    },
    watch:
    {
        searchText: function() {
            this.searchResult = this.search()
        }
    },
    methods:
    {
        search: function()
        {
            var result = [];
            var _self = this;

            $.getJSON("data/data.json", function(json) {                   
                $.each(json, function(index, obj) {
                    if (_self.searchText.length > 0 && obj.text.indexOf(_self.searchText) != -1)
                        result.push(obj);
                }, this);
            });

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

This code works well, but I don't understand why:

Why `search()` doesn't return an empty array without waiting for the result of `$.getJSON()` which is an asynchronous function? Surprisingly (for me), it only returns after the callback function is completed.

Comment: @JosephSilber already gave the right answer, but as a little extra, you could return `result.slice()` which create a copy of the array, in this context it'll be your snapshot. Then you should see it's indeed empty :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It indeed only returns an empty array.

However, since arrays in JS are passed by reference, the array you get back is the very same array from within the method. So when the AJAX request resolves, the items are added to that array, which is what you subsequently see.